# java : properties file escape sequence for square bracket

Tags: java, resourcebundle, properties-file

Need to escape the [ at the starting of a value.

I am using PropertyResourceBundle to read the properties file and i have a property whose value is starting with a square bracket like

```
myapp.add.user.email.selfRegistration.subject=[MYAPP] Welcome to MYAPP
```

when i try to read this file i get following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to
java.lang.String    at
java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:355)
```

i am using jdk7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.PropertyResourceBundle` is based on the `java.util.Properties`. Technically `java.util.Properties` implements `Map<Object,Object>` but when you load properties from a file the keys and values are restricted to `String` only (check the source of the `java.util.Properties.load()` methods). And the '[' character has no special meaning in the properties file format.

Hence it is impossible to get `ClassCastException` due to attempted cast of `String[]` to `String` if all your resource bundles are indeed based on property files.

Most likely you have a `ListResourceBundle`-based bundle (or a custom subclass of `ResourceBundle`) which *can* contain values of any type, arrays included.

And it is possible to mix property-based and class-based resources bundles with the same base name, for example the default resource bundle can be properties file while locale-specific child bundles are `ListResourceBundle`-based.

Comment: yes `ListResourceBundle` worked; but now i have extends the `PropertyResourceBundle` to handle my case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same with the below program and i am able to get the output from my program without any exception

can you check it and let me know if any other issues

```
package com.kb;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ResourceBundleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("mybundle");
        Enumeration <String> keys = rb.getKeys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = keys.nextElement();
            String value = rb.getString(key);
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `"String value = rb.getString(key);"` still throws the same exception

Comment: I am getting the output as myapp.add.user.email.selfRegistration.subject: [MYAPP] Welcome to MYAPP when i run the above program... what jdk version r u using ?

Comment: i am using java version 7

Comment: I ran the above code in Java 7 just now...its working very fine..please check whether your code is reading anything asString array and putting into String, because this kind of exception comes only during String[] assignment to String. or else post your entire code will have a look into it..